# Create a service to launch EXE or script

Tags: windows, windows-10, services, vbscript

How can I create a service that launches with Windows to run an EXE file or a VBScript before Windows login?

I am asking this because I have tried running a VBScript in task schedule while windows is logged off and it didn't work even tho I've tried to convert it to EXE which I have mentioned in another thread previously [here](https://superuser.com/q/1188975/673956)

Comment: It is possible. And doing it is outside the scope of this site. You should have asked it in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). But Windows itself can already do this through Task Scheduler and Group Policy.

Comment: @FleetCommand Ok I didn't know I should've have went there but it failed through the task schedule and didn't try it via gpo due the lack of information I couldn't find.

Comment: So, you should have asked about the failing of Task Scheduler to run a script at logon. It is not late, but you need to provide details as to what you did and what happened. You can edit your question.

Comment: @FleetCommand  I have already tried asking but no one bothered to answer why my script or exe fails to run with task schedule in another thread so I decided to see if it's possible to be ran as a service .

Comment: Check these Microsoft instructions: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/137890/how-to-create-a-user-defined-service

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445). Please explain what you're trying to accomplish instead of how you propose to accomplish it.

Comment: @Twisty : You over-edited. Why'd you remove the 1607 tag? Do you know why Elie may have placed that there? Also, you're "How can I" verbiage detracts me from wanting to answer the question now. Now, instead of providing a functioning way which may be rather automatic, I'm left with needing to describe how the person does it (so this should be a rather manual process, instead of being automatic), & I need to assess user's capabilities, else I'm really not answering the question as asked.  I've decided to see what further edits/rollbacks happen; the "Is it possible" text would be more answerable

Comment: @Twisty no it's not an XY problem i simply asked if it can be done so there is no problem yet or solution in my head until I give it a shot.

Comment: @TOOGAM indeed I tagged 1607 cause the version of windows is 1607.

Comment: @TOOGAM "Is it possible" can be answered with Yes or No. The next logical question is "How?" That's the underlying question being asked. As for removing the 1607 tag, there's nothing in that specific build of Windows that influences how to create a service to launch a program.

Comment: @Elie But why do you want to create a service? Even if you believe this isn't an XY problem, it will be helpful to anyone answering if you explain why you need a service to accomplish this task (versus a Scheduled Task, shortcut in the Startup folder, etc.)

Comment: @Twisty cause of this https://superuser.com/q/1188975/673956 I am trying to find an alternative solution by trying to use as much as possibilities as I can think of since I can't find an answer.

Comment: @Elie Fair enough. You need to include your underlying objective in your question, otherwise you are indeed asking an XY question.

Comment: @Twisty question has been edited

Comment: @Elie You're headed in the right direction!

Comment: @Twisty : You misunderstood.  My issue wasn't the word "how".  It was the word "I". That's how you really complicated things. If the Q. said "How can this be done?", I could simply answer using a technique that may be a bit advanced. Such an answer may help some users, & give others direction on what they may need to learn to accomplish the goal. However, saying "I" opened up a whole can of worms; a simple answer would not suitably answer the Q that was actually asked if the asker is novice. As I don't want to make a lengthy tutorial right now, Elie's question remains without an answer.

Comment: @TOOGAM I see your point. However, don't feel constrained to create such a specific answer that it only applies to the OP. In fact, the intent of my edit is to make the question useful to more than just the OP. So if your answer is also applicable to a broader audience, then its purpose on Super User has been accomplished. Of course, you should always endeavor to *also* provide a useful answer to the OP, and in this case use of the word **I** to keep the OP's need in focus is perfectly legitimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via [Microsoft - How To Create a User-Defined Service](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/137890/how-to-create-a-user-defined-service)

> To create a Windows NT user-defined service, perform the following
>   steps:
>
> 1. At a MS-DOS command prompt(running CMD.EXE), type the following command: `path\INSTSRV.EXE My Service path\SRVANY.EXE` where `path` is
>      the drive and directory of the Windows NT Resource Kit (i.e.,
>      C:\RESKIT) and `My Service` is the name of the service you are
>      creating.
>
>    - Example: `C:\Program Files\Resource Kit\Instsrv.exe Notepad C:\Program Files\Resource Kit\Srvany.exe`
>    - NOTE: To verify that the service was created correctly, check the registry to verify that the ImagePath value under
>        `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\service name` is
>        set to point to SRVANY.EXE. If this is not set correctly, the service
>        will stop shortly after it starts and return an Event ID 7000 "The
>        service name failed to start."
> 2. Run Registry Editor (Regedt32.exe)and locate the following subkey: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<My Service>`
> 3. From the Edit menu, click Add Key. Type the following and click OK: 
>      `Key Name: Parameters
>      Class : <leave blank>`
> 4. Select the Parameters key.
> 5. From the Edit menu, click Add Value. Type the following and click OK: `Value Name: Application Data Type : REG_SZ String :
>      <path>\<application.ext>` where `<path>\<application.ext>` is the
>      drive and full path to the application executable including the
>      extension (i.e., `C:\WinNT\Notepad.exe`)
> 6. Close Registry Editor.
>
> By default, a newly created service is configured to run Automatically
>   when the system is restarted.

Comment: Both answers from Steven Vascellaro and cb4 are correct i was able to create an EXE through a service but unfortunately i had same result which means 0 interaction from the EXE or the VBScript, I'd really hope that someone someday would figure it out as LogonExpert did, Many thanks.